# skImageDecoder::Factory returned null in android

Tags: java, android, web-services, http, httpresponse

I have written this code like

```
    private void handleResponse(String response) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    byte[] logo = Base64.decode(jsonObject.getString("hotel_logo"),
            Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap hotel_Logo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(logo, 0, logo.length);
    hotelLogo.setImageBitmap(hotel_Logo);

}
```

It shows **skImageDecoder::Factory returned null** in my app.what mistake i have done in this code?

Comment: code seem to be ok ... maybe data is wrong :P

Comment: @Selvin how can i check my data,whether is it correct?or what?